# json_encode function reads zero from volley but correct from Android Studio

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I have a php script within which I am checking the number of unpaid tickets belonging to a user. When I call the script on a web browser and pass the user id to it I get the expected response i.e -> `["unpaid_tickets","5","success"]`.
However when I call the same script from an Android application via `volley` library's `StringRequest` or `JsonArrayRequest` I keep getting zero for the value of the number of tickets despite using the same user id. response -> `["unpaid_tickets","0","success"]`.
How can I rectify this issue? I have tried adding the parameter to the `json_encode()`  function such as `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` but to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

PHP Script:

```
    $userid = $_GET['userid'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost",$username,$password,$database) or die('Cannot connect to database');

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS unpaid_tickets FROM tbl_tickets WHERE userid ='$userid' AND pay_status ='reserved'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die('Cannot execute query: '.mysqli_error($conn));


if($result){
    $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $tickets = $row[0];

    echo json_encode(array('unpaid_tickets',$tickets,'success'));
   // echo $tickets;

}else{
    echo json_encode(array('unpaid_tickets','0-0'));
}
```

Android Code:

```
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, AppController.getInstance().getURL(AppConst.TAG_URL_CHECK_UNPAID_TICKETS).equals("") ? AppConst.URL_CHECK_UNPAID_TICKETS : AppController.getInstance().getURL(AppConst.TAG_URL_CHECK_UNPAID_TICKETS), null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.i(TAG,"user id -> "+AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUserId());
                Log.w(TAG,"ticket check response -> "+response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG,"processUnpaidTicket() volley -> "+error.toString());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(AppConst.TAG_USER_ID, AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUserId());//add user id to request
                return params;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Unfortunately not a good type of question for this site. See **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**
read the SO tour.

Comment: You are going to need to show your PHP code dealing with the POST (or get or php://input) data. Chances are, your android app is sending as raw data, but your php script is using only $_GET or $_POST to read the 'id'.

Comment: @IncredibleHat added the php script

Comment: used both GET and POST getting same result @IncredibleHat

Comment: Yeah. It must be the way the android app is calling the request. If both get and post don't work, then you may try debugging with this at the top: `echo file_get_contents('php://input');` If it echos out something resembling your user id, then that is where its being passed in.

Comment: You may have to add the short block of android code as well, for how you are using StringRequest or JsonArrayRequest or even JsonObjectRequest. As from my understanding, it *should* be passing the value on the url as a GET parameter.

Comment: I've added the Android code @IncredibleHat